# How to decode XDR of the result_xdr

Tags: transactions, trustline, python-sdk

So my code is:

```
envelope = Te(tx=tx, opts={"network_id": "TESTNET"})
envelope.sign(receiving_account)

xdr = envelope.xdr()
response = horizon.submit(xdr)  # TO DO: Have to check if done well
print('CHANGE TRUST RESPONSE')
print(response['result_xdr'])
print('==========================================')
```

Unlike `Asset` and `Transaction` I find no way to decode the XDR of `TransactionResult`. On submitting the transaction I want to know whether it is successful or not.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

It is possible to decode XDR objects by using the `stellar_base.stellarxdr` module.

```python
from stellar_base.stellarxdr import Xdr
import base64

result_bytes = base64.b64decode(response['result_xdr'])
tx_result = Xdr.StellarXDRUnpacker(result_bytes).unpack_TransactionResult()

To get a hold of the contents as readable text:
import jsonpickle

p = jsonpickle.Pickler(keys=True)
print(p.flatten(tx_result))
```

Note that if you just want to check if the transaction was successful you can see that from the horizon response without the need to decode the transaction result.

Comment: Thanks for your response, it prints `TransactionResult(feeCharged=100, result=<stellar_base.stellarxdr.StellarXDR_pack.nullclass object at 0x10aa60ef0>, ext=<stellar_base.stellarxdr.StellarXDR_pack.nullclass object at 0x10aa79668>)`

From this, how do I extract the `result` part as it's shown in XDR?

I want to store the result text for audit purpose otherwise I know that JSON text should be suffice

Comment: For accepted valid transactions via Horizon, you get JSON like: {
  "_links": {
    "transaction": {
      "href": "https://horizon-testnet.XXX"
    }
  },
  "hash": "XXX",
  "ledger": 9072556,
  "envelope_xdr": "XXX",
  "result_xdr": "XXX",
  "result_meta_xdr": "XXX"
}......how about making a quick query against Horizon, using "hash" at http: //__HORIZON__/transactions/<<HASH>>?

Answer (score 0):

Or try the UI version for XDR decoder at Lab, if just handling a few XDR?

https://www.stellar.org/laboratory/#xdr-viewer?type=TransactionEnvelope&network=test

Need to choose the "XDR type".

Answer (score 0):

Added this to the answer:

To get a hold of the contents as readable text:

```
import jsonpickle

p = jsonpickle.Pickler(keys=True)
print(p.flatten(tx_result))
```