# How can I get the value of the Stellar Transaction?

Tags: transactions, accounts, payments, xdr, python-sdk

Greetings Stellar StackExchange community,

I would kindly require your assistance as I am having hard time figuring out how to get the incoming transaction amount value, and what would be the most appropriate way to do it for my personal account.

Currently I have function which return transactions, but this ones include memo, fees, hash, xdr_envelope and so on, however not amount. What I need for my "app" is TX HASH, MEMO, VALUE and PAGING token as I am storing them into database.

```
def get_transactions(self):
        data = server.transactions().for_account(account_id=self.public_key).include_failed(False).call()
        for tx in data['_embedded']['records']:
            te = TransactionEnvelope.from_xdr(tx['envelope_xdr'], Network.TESTNET_NETWORK_PASSPHRASE)
            pprint(te)
```

While pretty printing each TransactionEnvelope, I am getting back object but not values.

I have been as well looking at the post [How to decode XDR of the result_xdr](https://stellar.stackexchange.com/questions/1055/how-to-decode-xdr-of-the-result-xdr) however due to the new package for python I "hit the wall".

I tried as well use Payments For Account while amount is returned however there is no Memo.

```
 data = server.payments().for_account(account_id=self.public_key).call()
 pprint(data['_embedded']['records'])
```

Could you please help me resolve the issues I am having?

thank you for your time, answer and assistance in advance, and hope to get response soon.

best regards

Animus

Answer (score 1):

A stellar transaction consists of one *or more* operations such as payment, createAccount, setOptions.

I'm not familiar with python-sdk but I think like in other sdk's the transaction object should also have a `operations` method or property which should deliver all related operations. You have to iterate through the operations of a given transaction (`for op in tx['operations']`), figure out if it is a payment operation (`if op['type'] == 'payment'`) and then access asset and amount on that object (`op['asset']`, `op['amount']`)

Answer (score 1):

At first, I recommend you read [this article](https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/concepts/transactions.html), which describes the composition of a transaction.

Hope this example helps.

```
from stellar_sdk import TransactionEnvelope, Network, TextMemo, IdMemo, HashMemo, ReturnHashMemo, Payment

envelope_xdr = 'AAAAAD11sXdkWzZ8LQrxr5zWXdrI6CK5Pz/+e3RGX8RqzmPYAAAAyAAAAAAAAABlAAAAAAAAAAEAAAAKaGVsbG8gbWVtbwAAAAAAAgAAAAAAAAABAAAAANBtml/avnYRS9MeyvimlMQRJU/oq1JvHfDviocRc6feAAAAAAAAAAA7wO+gAAAAAAAAAAEAAAAAGH7pPQgWjoQcf+QW/EeDjc6Y1T1/j10jRm9kjpyvCXsAAAABWENOAAAAAACHPQ4p8zj3+dCkTJ/erv3iHXpZxAesYy04momcXmgwKwAAAAA7wO+gAAAAAAAAAAFqzmPYAAAAQBDpbZ5Nf6lv2yvxwEF0K7Sxtvft3vojJRrSAGvlnQwn9fHWAK6876/Abb0OtBUOvpxzyNrBagWGttvAiJLbaQU='

te = TransactionEnvelope.from_xdr(envelope_xdr, Network.TESTNET_NETWORK_PASSPHRASE)
tx_hash = te.hash_hex()
print(f"hash: {tx_hash}")
raw_memo = te.transaction.memo
memo = None
if isinstance(raw_memo, TextMemo):
    memo = raw_memo.memo_text
if isinstance(raw_memo, IdMemo):
    memo = raw_memo.memo_id
if isinstance(raw_memo, HashMemo):
    memo = raw_memo.memo_hash
if isinstance(raw_memo, ReturnHashMemo):
    memo = raw_memo.memo_return
print(f"memo: {memo}")
operations = te.transaction.operations
for op in operations:
    # You can check other types of operations here.
    # You can find list of operations here: https://stellar-sdk.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#operation
    if isinstance(op, Payment):
        amount = op.amount
        asset_code = op.asset.code
        asset_issuer = op.asset.issuer
        destination = op.destination
        source = op.source or te.transaction.source.public_key
        print(f"{source} send {amount} {asset_code}({asset_issuer}) to {destination}")
```

Comment: Thank you for response