# How to decode XDR of the result_xdr in python with stellar_sdk

Tags: python-sdk

I want to retrieve transaction details from the response message. The same could be possible queering a horizon, but it seems an unnecessary waste of resources to send additional requests to the horizon if the information is already received.

A very exact question has been asked 3 years ago
[How to decode XDR of the result_xdr](https://stellar.stackexchange.com/questions/1055/how-to-decode-xdr-of-the-result-xdr)
but the solution is based on the old *stellar_base* library.

I assume I should use *from_xdr()* function, but unsure which object to attach to.

````
response = server.submit_transaction(transaction)
tx_result = ???.from_xdr(response["result_xdr"])
print(f"xdr_result: {tx_result}")```
````

Answer (score 0):

Was working recently working on a project and came across the same issue. While digging through the `stellar-sdk`code I found out that it has an `xdr` module which you can use to decode information from the `result_xdr`

Let's work with the following `TransactionResult` for as an example.[image]

To obtain the `offerId` we can do this:

```
from stellar_sdk.xdr import TransactionResult

tx_result = TransactionResult.from_xdr(response['result_xdr'])
offer_id = tx_result.result.results[0].tr.manage_sell_offer_result.success.offers_claimed[0].offer_id

print(offer_id)
<Int64 [int64=359738]>
```